# Can I temporarily run ADS on both the old server and a new replacement server?

Tags: advantage-database-server

I am running advantage database server version 8.10.0.38 on a windows 2000 server.  I want to replace the server with a new windows 2008 R2 server and migrate the ADS and application to the new server.  I need to test the application on the new server for a week before removing the license from the old server.  Can I install the license on the new server and run both the old and new servers with the one license for a week?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the legality of doing that (even though the intent of what your are doing certainly seems reasonable). From a practical standpoint, though, it may not work. Advantage Database Server attempts to detect if other servers are running with the same serial number, so it is quite possible that the second instance of Advantage will not start up.

There is an additional potential problem as well.  v8.x is not officially supported on Win 2008 R2, so there are potential problems with that (I have not tried it, so I do not know for sure if it will work or not). It would be necessary to move to v10.x to have support for Win 2008 R2.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually planning on windows 2008 32-bit not the R2 I had listed in the question.